# Get the 10 lastest not blank value cell in one column

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

This formula looks for the last cell that is not blank in a specific column. I'd like to get the values from the last 10 nonempty cells in the column.

```
=FILTER(H:H , ROW(H:H) =MAX( FILTER( ROW(H:H) , NOT(ISBLANK(H:H)))))
```

At the moment I can get the value of the last non-empty cell, I would like to know what I need to adjust in order to get the values of the last 10 non-empty cells of a specific column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use query instead:

```
=QUERY(A:A, "where A is not null offset "&COUNTA(A:A)-10, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! @player0